# How to generate a list of URLs in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, xargs

How can I generate a list of URLs in bash so that I can pipe them to xargs and then to curl?

```
http://somewebsite.com/{}.file
```

where `{}` is a number.

Comment: `echo http://somewebsite.com/{1..100}.file`

Comment: @IporSircer Wow that simple. But what about a new line?

Comment: I found a solution using seq.

Comment: @Testr, good. Now, you can answer yourself here.

Answer (score 3):

As Ipor Sircer said, you can use `echo http://somewebsite.com/{1..100}.file | xargs ...`. If you want newlines between entries (which doesn't matter for xargs), use `printf '%s\n' http://somewebsite.com/{1..100}.file`. But for something like what you're describing, a `for` loop might be better:

```
for url in http://somewebsite.com/{1..100}.file; do
    curl "$url"
done
```

That way if you need any additional per-file scripting (which I often do with things like this), you can write it directly, rather than having to figure out how to embed it in an `xargs` target.